# mysql via subprocess doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

```
import os
import subprocess
cmdline = ['mysql -u"username" -p"password" < query.sql']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
retcode = p.wait()
```

That's my code to connect to mysql and execute query.sql. Looks good to me, but it doesn't work and the bad thing is that I don't get any error message at all. retcode is 1 and from stdout, stderr I only get the mysql standard text "Usage mysql [OPTIONS] [Database] ..." so I thought my syntax is wrong. But it's not. I tested the line of code in terminal and it works.

Does python have a problem to execute this via subprocess? I just want an easy way to execute this small mysql code.
Thanks.

Comment: Should username and password be in "" or is that just formatting for the question? And where is query.sql ? Is it on the path? Try an `ls` to be sure. And possibly there should be a space between -u and username (and password)

Comment: yes, username and password should be in "". query.sql is in the same dir as the python script. Is the space between -u and username (and password) important? I will test that

Answer (score 7):

```
cmdline = ['mysql -u"username" -p"password" < query.sql']
```

This is not the way to use `Popen`. The program must be the first element of the list, and each argument that should be passed must be an element of the list, too. So it should rather be `cmdline = ["mysql", "-u", username, "-p", password]`. Furthermore, this is not the shell, so you can't simply use "< query.sql". Instead, use the `stdin = PIPE` parameter and then pass the SQL query like `p.communicate(sqlQuery)`.

```
retcode = p.wait()
```

You already waited for the process to end using `.communicate()`, so you should access the return value with the `p.returncode` attribute.

Comment: I had issues unless I had `-p` and password as the same arg ... ie. `subprocess.call(["mysql", "-u", username, "-p%s" % password, "-e", "SELECT @@hostname"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer but if you are trying to call MySQL from python it will usually be easier and more controllable to call via a DBAPI library [see python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL) or going further as ORM like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

An Example for calling mySQL is [here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html)